# Don't Require Last Character of Repeated Pattern Regex

Tags: regex

I have an HTML5 input which accepts a string of unknown length of comma-delimited 5-digit numbers. All 3 of the following would be valid inputs:

- 12345
- 12345,12345
- 12345,12345,12345

and on into (theoretically) an infinite number.

I am using a regex to validate. It's *almost* working, but what I have now requires a trailing comma, which is unnecessary.

My existing attempts: `([0-5][0-9][0-4][0-9][1-6],)*` (requires a trailing comma) and `([0-5][0-9][0-4][0-9][1-6],?)*` (too broad, will validate something like 1234512345 with no comma).

I don't know much about regex, am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the optional part starts with `,`, what you need is this:

```
[0-5][0-9][0-4][0-9][1-6](,[0-5][0-9][0-4][0-9][1-6])*
```

It's unfortunate that you have a complicated requirement that requires duplication in the RE, but if you relax that constraint, you could do something more concise like this:

```
[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*
```

or even this depending upon whether you can use POSIX-extended expressions:

```
\d+(,\d+)*
```

which makes it a bit easier to see what the first one is doing.

Comment: Unfortunately can't relax the constraints as the string is a specific list of codes, but this will work perfectly. Thank you!